# how to Share NuGet on team

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a solution with 6 R&D projects in it.  Recently we upgraded to Visual Studio 2013 and after upgrading the solution I added a 7th project (ASP.net MVC) which added a packages folder to my solution folder.

I recently added my solution and projects to our production share which is shared across 3 other developers.  We have a libraries subfolder that our production solution references.  Discussing my newly added solution and project folders to our production environment with our build developer, he would like to see the packages folder moved as a subfolder of the Libraries subfolder and all the team reference the single packages folder at that location.  We do not use Team Foundation.

Since I did not tell nugget where to create the packages (they were just placed in the solution folder) is there a way to tell it where to look for the packages after I move the folder to its new location?  How will the other developers configure their Visual Studio instance to look at the shared folder instead of their local machine?  Assuming, once they build the solution locally it will also add a local packages folder and we don't want that.

Seems like this is pretty straight forward.  In fact, NuGet site says you can share packages folder but it says you have to modify nuget.config and I don't have that in my solution.  Any thoughts/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, why does the build developer care where the packages folder is located? Nuget has a convention for this exact purpose - let it handle where the packages are located (and MSBuild will auto-grab and place the libraries if he has set his up properly).

Comment: I think the issue really is around the bloat with each developer having packages in their local repository and then during check-in each one is moving essentially the same "packages".  He may not care ultimately, but he was the one that brought the redundancy up.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. If the packages are in the official Nuget repo, you can pull from there. If they are "internal" packages, I would recommend on setting up your own internal Nuget repo. You really want to avoid pointing to a shared folder for packages. I just moved a client away from that due to the many deployment problems they experienced in that particular setup (not to mention adding a new dev onto the project).

Comment: Here is an example...In my R&D project I used EF6.  NuGet added the files to the packages folder locally.  Now that I have moved the R&D into production, should every dev have a packages folder containing EF6 or should we have a single repository for the package(s) that are simply "pointed to" within the solution.  I'm not seeing the value in each having their own internal repository.

Answer (score 0):

Nuget, in and of itself, is a package management repository. It's entire purpose is to allow you to centrally pull down packages (libraries, configurations, whatever) that you need to a place locally on your system (whether it's dev, production, whatever) without having to actually commit those libraries to your source control. Instead, any developer will just be committing a file that says the equivalent of, "Get me a package by this ID (name) and version."

This process creates a file called packages.config at the top level of every project within your solution. The file would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The files themselves are placed in the projects where they need to be (in the case of projects like jQuery) or, library binaries are stored at the top-level of your solution in a folder called *packages* and **should not be checked into source control**.

You can also enable "auto-restore" packages for Nuget so that when anybody checks out your project, they will automatically get the libraries and things they need in order for your project to run/build correctly.

This means that everybody gets what they need, you do not need to manage your own "library repository" (please...no shared folders!), and, at any point, you can look at the packages.conf folder to see what your project depends on.

Here are some more links on how to enable and work with Nuget for development and build systems. There are scores of other resources on the web as well.

- [Introduction to Nuget](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNuGetPackageManagementForNETAnotherPieceOfTheWebStack.aspx)
- [Using NuGet Without Committing Packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages)
- [Package Restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore)